# Remove item in nested list based on probability of a nested list

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, nested-lists

So I want to remove duplicate item in nested list while keep the nested structure, decision of remove which item is based on probability. Here is what I have:

```
import collections

new_sample = collections.defaultdict(list, {"dv1": [[3, 141], [13]], "dv2":[[3, 141], [157]], "dv3":[[0],[2]]})
new_sample_proba = collections.defaultdict(list, {"dv1": [[0.8, 0.9], [0.9]], "dv2": [[0.9, 0.8], [0.9]], "dv3": [[0.9], [0.95]]})

print("before fix: ",new_sample)
print("before fix: ",new_sample_proba)
full_views_list = list(new_sample.keys())
temp_views_list = list(new_sample.keys())
for curr_view in full_views_list:
    print("t1 ",new_sample[curr_view])
    print("t1 ",new_sample_proba[curr_view])
    temp_views_list.remove(curr_view)
    for i, curr_class_new in enumerate(new_sample[curr_view]):
        temp_pop_list = []
        for j, class_item in enumerate(curr_class_new):
            print(class_item)
            for other_view in temp_views_list:
                print("t2 org",new_sample[other_view])
                print("t2 org",new_sample_proba[other_view])
                for l, other_view_class_new in enumerate(new_sample[other_view]):
                    for m, other_class_item in enumerate(other_view_class_new):
                        # only perform delete if current view contain item, if it's deleted, move on
                        if new_sample[curr_view][i][j] == new_sample[other_view][l][m]:
                            if new_sample_proba[curr_view][i][j]>new_sample_proba[other_view][l][m]:
                                new_sample[other_view][l].pop(m)
                                new_sample_proba[other_view][l].pop(m)
                                print("t2 update",new_sample)
                                print("t2 update",new_sample_proba)
                            else:
                                temp_pop_list.append(j)
                            print(class_item, "check")
        temp_pop_list.sort(reverse=True)
        for idx in temp_pop_list:
            new_sample[curr_view][i].pop(idx)
            new_sample_proba[curr_view][i].pop(idx)

print("apply fix: ",new_sample)
print("apply fix: ",new_sample_proba)
```

So the code above works, How can I make it shorter?

Comment: can you please explain what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: Please provide input and expected output for 3 or 4 samples (to see how they should "conflict", each with each? only "neighbors"?...?)